# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drf_spectacular.views'

Tags: python, django, drf-spectacular

urls.py

```
from drf_spectacular.views import SpectacularAPIView, SpectacularRedocView, 
SpectacularSwaggerView
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='api-schema'),
    path('api/docs/', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='api-schema'), name='api-docs'),
    path('api/redoc/', SpectacularRedocView.as_view(url_name='api-schema'), name='api-redoc'),
    path('api/user/', include('user.urls')),
    path('api/recipe/', include('recipe.urls')),
]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'drf_spectacular',
'core',
'user',
'recipe',
]
```

requirements.txt

```
drf-spectacular
# drf-spectacular>=0.15,<0.16

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

I'm trying to add Swagger UI in Django API, but I'm getting this error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drf_spectacular.views'.
[image]

Comment: Check you've installed it properly try to run this command `pip freeze` and look for **drf_spectacular** package

Comment: Check the dir of your venv if the views.py within the package exists

Comment: I've installed drf_spectacular in my virtual environment.

Comment: Follow these instructions for installing [drf spectacular](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#installation) properly. If you're using **Docker** to execute your code, add this dependency to requirements.txt like ```drf-spectacular==0.22.1``` (whatever your version)

Comment: Did you solved finally ? I have the same problem......

Comment: Yes it was python version issue

Comment: What do you mean ? Could you post the solution please ? "Python version issue" what does it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Windows VSCode, solved it by installing it outside venv. I havent checked why but it seems relate to dependencies version or just good'ol Path.

Comment: Hello, please add more details about your answer, it shouldn't contain phrases like "haven't checked", especially if it's in 1 of 2 sentences.

Answer (score 0):

For me when I placed "drf_spectacular" at end in INSTALLED_APPS it worked!

like INSTALLED_APPS = [ ...  , 'drf_spectacular']

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `'drf_spectacular'` to the end of the `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

The order in INSTALLED_APPS affects the order in which apps are initialized by Django. If drf_spectacular needs to inspect or integrate with other apps, those apps should be initialized before drf_spectacular.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35510879)